# Orderby month and year using linq

Tags: linq, date, sql-order-by

I'm fetching distinct months from database but the month values are in the form of month and year. ie, **Jan-15,Feb-15**. How do I get it in Ascending order of both month and year?
Right now I'm getting result as: **Apr-15 Feb-15 Jan-15 Mar-15**. But I want the result like this: **Jan-15 Feb-15 Mar-15 Apr-15**.

```
 var months = ((from mnths in context.Table
                       orderby mnths.Month
                       select mnths.Month).Distinct()).ToList();

        return months;
```

Thanks.

Comment: Why are the months like `Jan-15` and why don't you use a single `DateTime` column which includes the month, the year and all other date and time portions? Never store datetimes as strings. That's what you have to fix.

Comment: I am fetching it from DB and in DB it is already stored in that format (Jan-15). I'm not supposed to change the format :(  @Tim Schmelter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `DateTime.TryParseExact` like this:

```
var months = ((from mnths in context.Table
                   orderby mnths.Month
                   select mnths.Month).Distinct()).ToList().OrderBy(m =>
                   {
                        DateTime month;
                        return DateTime.TryParseExact(m, new[] {"MMM-yy"}, DateTimeFormatInfo.InvariantInfo, DateTimeStyles.None, out month)
                            ? month
                            : DateTime.MinValue;
                   }).ToList();
```

You need to call `ToList` before `OrderBy` so the original query is executed and you get an `IEnumerable<string>` instead of an `IQueryable`.

Comment: After I used your code, I'm getting the error like this, **a lambda expression with a statement body cannot be converted to an expression tree** @Rene Vogt

Comment: @UserAR updated the answer. You need to call `ToList` before `OrderBy` to execute the query and get an `IEnumerable`

Comment: Thanks a lot!! :) @Rene Vogt

Comment: this does not answers the question.

Answer (score 0):

Just use .NET Sort Method.
First Get All dates from DB

```
var dates = ((from dts in context.Table
                         select dts).Distinct().ToList();

            return dates;
```

And then Do

```
dates.Sort();
dates.Reverse();
```

And you'll get the result as yo want. (And Store Datetime in Db with type datetime not nvarchar or other).

Comment: does not contains a definition for sort.